# Как запретить закрытие файла .exe? Если компилировать .py в .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что нужно написать, чтобы запретить закрытие программы, а потом чтобы она автоматический закрывалась. Я хочу написать программу которую нельзя будет закрыть, и чтобы она сама по истечению времени закрывалась. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос звучит так как если бы вы писали какое-то вредоносное программное обеспечение, надеюсь я ошибаюсь и речь идет о каком-то важном процессе который нужно защитить от пользователей.

1. Процесс можно запускать под учетной записью администратора и тогда обычные пользователи вряд ли смогут его закрыть (все зависит и от операционной системы о которой в вопросе ничего не сказано)
2. Процесс может запускаться специальным хелпером, который следит за наличием процесса в памяти, количеством таких процессов и при необходимости запускает новые.

НО в любом случае процесс всегда можно завершить, если интерфейс вашей программы это не позволяет, всегда можно использовать для завершения нежелательных процессов интерфейс операционной системы.

Answer (score 0):

Никак, всегда можно кильнуть процесс.
Ну а если там гуи, тогда можно заблокировать/скрыть кнопку закрытия.

## Tkinter

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.mainloop()
```

## PyQt5

```
QtGui.QMainWindow(parent=None, flags=QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

## Auto-close Tkinter

```
root.after(30000, lambda: w.destroy()) # Destroy the widget after 30 seconds
```